# Instagram Multiprocessing with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

Hey all trust that you're well, I'm trying to run multiple Instagram accounts parallel using **Multiprocessing** and **Selenium**, how would I go about logging into different accounts with every process created.

I tried using a json file with a while loop however I haven't made much progress.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

```
import time
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Pool

f = open('accounts.json',)
datas = json.load(f)

def get_data(url):

    Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    mobile_emulation = {
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
    Options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    Options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

    bot = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options, executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
    bot.set_window_size(500, 768)
    bot.get(url=url)
    
    time.sleep(10)

    # Login section==========================
    print('Logging in...')
    bot.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    username_field = bot.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/input')
    username_field.send_keys(data["username"])
    time.sleep(5)
    password_field = bot.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/label/input')
    password_field.send_keys(data["password"])
    time.sleep(5)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[6]/button').click()
    time.sleep(6)
    bot.close()
    bot.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_count = int(input("Enter the number of processes: "))
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
    urls_list = [url] * process_count
    print(urls_list)
    p = Pool(processes=process_count)
    p.map(get_data, urls_list)
    while True:
        for data in datas:
            get_data()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just use an index and store the credentials in an array and then pass the index to the function.

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan hope you're well, may you please assist with an example.

Comment: @soundwave hope you're well, when I run the script, I am prompted to **input** the **number of processes**. Upon selecting a value I would like to **assign** a different **Instagram account** to each **process**

Comment: Aren't the accounts info inside `accounts.json`?

Comment: @soundwave they are, however, if I input 2 for example it creates 2 processes and reads the first value in the `accounts.json` twice instead of selecting the second value, my question is how would I go about assigning different accounts to different values.

Comment: If you run `for data in datas: print(data)` does it print different values?

Comment: @soundwave it prints the same value twice, considering that the input was two, once the process is complete it then runs the program again and uses the second value in the json file.

Comment: So the problem is that in `accounts.json` the second username is equal to the first one and the second password is equal to the first one?

Comment: incorrect, if I insert 
`for data in datas:
        print(data)`

above the `process_count = int(input("Enter the number of processes: "))`

it prints the two separate values if I place it after or within the def function it just duplicates the first value and upon completion reads the second value.

Comment: mm did you try to write `def get_data(data):` and inside the while loop write `for data in datas: get_data(data)`

Comment: may you please assist with an example.

Comment: ok i will write it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script uses `threading` (instead of `multiprocessing`) to open multiple independent windows (instances) of the browser. The code contained in the function `test_instance` is run simultaneously in each window.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
import json

def test_instance(data):
    Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    mobile_emulation = {"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Mobile Safari/535.19"}
    Options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    Options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

    bot = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options, executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
    bot.set_window_size(500, 768)
    bot.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    
    time.sleep(10)

    # Login section==========================
    print('Logging in...')
    bot.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    username_field = bot.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/input')
    username_field.send_keys(data['username'])
    time.sleep(5)
    password_field = bot.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/label/input')
    password_field.send_keys(data['password'])
    time.sleep(5)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[6]/button').click()
    time.sleep(6)
    
    bot.quit()

f = open('accounts.json',)
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
process_count = 2 # number of tests to run (each test open a separate browser)
thread_list = []

# Start test
for i in range(process_count):
    t = threading.Thread(name=f'Test {i}', target=test_instance, args=[data[i]])
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.name + ' started')
    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print('Test completed')
```

Comment: NameError: name 'url' is not defined

Comment: TypeError: get_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Comment: @DonEros That's strange, i will add soon a new method, but to complete it i need the structure of your file `accounts.json`. I don't need the explicit usernames and passwords, so replace them with other words such as user1 password1, user2 password2 etc and then paste the code here https://pastebin.com/, then click "create new paste" in the bottom of the page and send me the link. Could you do this? Thanks

Comment: no problem, 

https://pastebin.com/Kep4scL9

I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: @DonEros you are welcome! try the new code and let me know

Comment: This scripts works, however, not as I intended, I would like to run the test parallel (at the same time)

Comment: I've removed the `time.sleep()` and still receive the same result

Comment: `line 43
    t = threading.Thread(name=f'Test {i}', target=test_instance(username, password)args=[data[i]])
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?`

Comment: @DonEros Actually that line is `t = threading.Thread(name=f'Test {i}', target=test_instance, args=[data[i]])` try to refresh the site

Comment: You're a star @sound wave. truly appreciate all the assistance.